# Why would an aDSL connection less than a block away be 3x faster?

Tags: networking, router, internet

I live in a fairly remote area, less than approx. 2 miles from the central office. Our internet speed is listed on the router page as "1344 Kbps / 192 Kbps" - however I have asked the neighbors for their information and they reported "3712 Kbps / 448 Kbps" - why the discrepancy? We have the fastest service they offer.

For the past few days our internet has been off. No explanation except that there was an "outage" - the tech later remarked that the "port was down". Our neighbors had no such problems.

We have made repeated calls to tech support for previous issues with stability - while they have never found any problems in our lines, the only solution we have found is to replace the DSL filter with another one. This seems to work for a few days until it needs to be repeated.

Aside from that, placing the routers power supply on a surge protector and disabling wireless seems to have increased stability. Later today we should get a call back from a tech, are there any further questions I should ask, or things I can do to determine why our neighbors internet seems faster and has greater stability?

Comment: Thanks for the information. After manually inspecting the junction box we replaced a few sections of wire, and instantly our modem was connecting at over 3mb. We plan on replacing other sections under the house and other boxes.

Comment: It sounds like you solved the problem.  If so, could you post it as an answer and accept it?  That will let people know that it has been solved.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

One thing that could be making your connection slow is joins or repairs in the line.  When there is a join in the wire to your house, especially if it is old, not well done, or a bit corroded, there can be some reflection or echo inside the wire.  This means that the modems at each end may need to slow down their transmission rate so that they can tell the difference between the reflection and a real signal.

So it may be worth getting your telephone line checked.

Comment: As an old telco guy, all three answers are correct, but this is probably the easiest to fix. Throw a phone cable out the window on the side of the house where the 'demarc' (demarcation, aka the beige box where the phone wire enters the house), and bypass house wiring by connecting directly at the demarc to your DSL 'modem' (which is not really a modem, but everybody calls it one). Then, see if the speed changes. If so, your house wiring is the culprit, or maybe one of your DSL filters needs replacing.

Answer (score 2):

You should ask the Tech if getting a dedicated splitter will improve the quality of the connection, and also if there are any [bridge-taps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_tap) or similar in the line which can be removed.

The idea of a dedicated splitter is that they are less prone to failure, and will provide better performance (I suspect because of less noise) by splitting off the DSL signal in 1 place rather then having multiple filters for each phone.  You mentioned that replacing your filters seemed to fix things for a short time - it may be related.

A Bridge Tap changes the impedence of the line and can stuff up your connection.

Answer (score 1):

There may be differences in terminologies used around the world, but essentially, and ADSL service runs on your PSTN line, back to a Telephone Exchange (or first to a repeater of some sort, then on to the Exchange).

The length of the telephone cable the runs from your premises to the Exchange is a major factor in determining the speed and quality of your connection.

Unfortunately, just because you are a short distance away from your neighbor, doesn't mean that your are on a cable of similar lenghth, as they don't run in direct line "as the crow flies".

It's quite common for cables to take detours, depending on the infrastructures available, resulting in lower speed and stability. The ISP probably won't reveal exactly what's between you and their equipment, but if there's anything like a "repeater", it will definitely reduce your speed even further.